# How to in Javascript execute multiple animations in sequence, each having a delay

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am trying to animate the tower of Hanoi problem. My current format for the animation relies on moving each wooden piece individually. Each movement for a piece requires an animation. My function that solves the problem calls the function that will then move the respective piece.

```
function hanoi(n, source, destination, buffer){
if (n == 1){
    var newBlock = source.stack.pop()

    destination.stack.push(newBlock);
    moveBlock(newBlock, destination.x - source.x + newBlock.x, 500 - 62 * (1 + destination.stack.length));
} else {
    hanoi(n-1, source, buffer, destination);

    var newBlock = source.stack.pop()
    destination.stack.push(newBlock);
    moveBlock(newBlock, destination.x - source.x + newBlock.x, 500 - 62 * (1 + destination.stack.length));

    hanoi(n-1, buffer, destination, source);
}
}
```

The moveBlock function is fairly janky as I was having problems putting a delay into the animation itself. For the three segments of the movement animation it calls different functions. I do all this because I just can't understand how to put a freaking delay in Javascript effectively.

```
function moveBlock(block, x2, y2){
    var id = setInterval(moveUp, speed);
    function moveUp() {
        if (block.y <= 50){
            draw();
            clearInterval(id);
            moveBlockOver(block, x2, y2);
        } else {
            block.y = block.y - 5;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
function moveBlockOver(block, x2, y2){
    var negative = -(block.x - x2)/(Math.abs(block.x - x2));
    var id = setInterval(moveOver, speed);
    function moveOver() {
        if (block.x == x2){
            draw();
            clearInterval(id);
            moveBlockDown(block, x2, y2);
        } else {
            block.x = block.x + 5 * negative;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
function moveBlockDown(block, x2, y2){
    var id = setInterval(moveDown, speed);
    function moveDown() {
        if (block.y >= y2){
            draw();
            go = true;
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            block.y = block.y + 5; 
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

How could I better format my code to solve this problem? It would be much simpler if I could just put a delay in javascript code but apparently that's impossible.

Comment: Delays aren't impossible. [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). Also, I know this isn't an answer, but I just wanna recommend the [CreateJS](http://createjs.com) libraries.

Comment: When should delay occur?

Comment: There is a delay between the individual movements of each block. On the way up, there is a delay of  `speed`
between each movement of 5 pixels. Same thing on the way over and on the way down.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: I'm not too handy with stacksnippets and I have some external files involved. I uploaded the code to my site [here](http://statseven.com/developer/help.html)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` use `requestAnimationFrame`

```
var playing = true;
function update(timer) { // Main update loop
    // your draw code

    if(playing){
        requestAnimationFrame(update); // get next frame
    }
}
requestAnimationFrame(update); // starts the animation
```

To do the animation create some functions for each anim that returns `true` when done

```
function anim1(){
    drawFoo(); // draw function
    foo.x += 5;
    return foo.x > 100; // returns true when foo.x > 100
}

function anim2(){
    drawFoo(); // draw function
    foo.y += 5;
    return foo.y > 100; // returns true when foo.y > 100
}

function anim3(){
    drawFoo(); // draw function
    foo.x -= 5;
    return foo.x < 0; // returns true when foo.x < 0
}
```

Then create a stack with the animation functions in order that they need to be run, and a var to hold the current animation

```
 // repeat 2 times
var animStack = [anim1,anim2,anim3,anim1,anim2,anim3];
var currentAnim;
```

Then in the `update` loop

```
 if(currentAnim === undefined){ // is there an animation 
     // no animation 
     if(animStack.length > 0){  // are there any animations on the stack
         currentAnim = animStack.shift(); // yes get the first anim
     }else{
         playing = false;  // no animations to play so stop and exit
         return;
     }
 }
 if(currentAnim()){ // call the anim and check if returns true;
     // animation ended so get the next animation function if there are any
     if(animStack.length > 0){
         currentAnim = animStack.shift(); // get the next anim
     }else{
         playing = false; // no more animations so stop
         currentAnim = undefined; // ready for new animtion
     }
 }
```

The anim functions will play one after the other until done. To add new animations just push them onto the anim stack and call the `startAnimation` function

```
function startAnimation(){  // function restarts the anim safely
    if(!playing){  // has the animation stopped
        playing = true;   // yes then restart
        requestAnimationFrame(update)`
    }
    // if the animation is playing then no need to restart
}
```